# Regarding socle of a C* algebra

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I wanted to know if the socle of a complex C*-algebra is essential?

Can anyone suggest a text where the socle is studied in detail. I tried reading it from the book by Bernard Aupetit, *A Primer in spectral theory*. But the books says to know about socle more, refer to the book by Aupetit, *Propriétés spectrales des algèbres de Banach*, which is in French.

Comment: Please see (esp. section 5 in) the paper https://doi.org/10.5186/aasfm.1969.428

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the socle of a C${}^*$-algebra is the smallest closed ideal containing all the minimal closed ideals? Then the answer is no, e.g., $C[0,1]$ has no minimal ideals so its socle is zero.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind to provide a reference where I can study Socle. or does an english translation of the above book exist?

Comment: No idea, sorry ...

Comment: @user531706 The text *Complete Normed Algebras* by Bonsall and Duncan is supposed to have a treatment of socles.  I haven't read that book but Blackadar and Kirchberg reference Bonsall and Duncan for "the general theory of socles of Banach algebras"